# i am making a password manager with tkinter in python

Tags: python, tkinter

i stock my password in a json file.
i have a function to display passwords and load 3 button for each: one that copy the password, an other that edit the password and the last that delete the password.
here is my function:

```py
def view_password(self):
        height = 1
        
        tk.Label(master=self.main_frame, text="Password List:").grid(row=height-1, column=0, sticky="w", pady=(0, 10))
        tk.Button(self.main_frame,text="new password",command=lambda:self.new_password()).grid(row=height-1, column=1, sticky="w", pady=(0, 10))
        

        for element in self.data["password"]:
            tk.Label(master=self.main_frame, text=self.data["application"][height-1]+": "+self.data["username"][height-1]+"\nPassword: "+element).grid(row=height, column=0, sticky="w", pady=(0, 10))
            
            tk.Button(master=self.main_frame,text="copy "+ element,command=lambda :self.copy(element)).grid(row=height, column=2, sticky="w", pady=(0, 10))
            tk.Button(master=self.main_frame,text="change password",command=lambda:self.window_change(height-1)).grid(row=height, column=3, sticky="w", pady=(0, 10))
            tk.Button(master=self.main_frame,text="delete",command=lambda:self.delete(height-1)).grid(row=height, column=4, sticky="w", pady=(0, 10))
```

the problem is that every button do an action for the last password in the window.I thought about send the id of the button in the command to associate it with the password but i don't know how to do

Comment: The title should reflect a narrow, specific technical problem your question is focused on, not what kind of program you were writing when you encountered that problem.

Comment: That said, it would make things much clearer if you explicitly encapsulated state; f/e, `command = functools.partial(lambda element: ..., element)`

Comment: ...one of the linked duplicates has an even better approach: `command = lambda element=element: ...`